# How to prevent JSON double encoding

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask

I have this object in python in the flask framework:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('54522c44b8f9100002223fc0'), u'streetNo': u'116', u'firstName': u'Emre', u'middleName': u'n/a', u'lastName': u'S', u'creation': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 30, 12, 17, 8, 727000), u'email': u'dean@c.edu', u'streetName': u'Columbia'}
```

when I go json.dumps(object, default=json_util.default), it become the following:

```
'{"_id": {"$oid": "54522c44b8f9100002223fc0"}, "streetNo": "116", "firstName": "Emre", "middleName": "n/a", "lastName": "S", "creation": {"$date": 1414671428727}, "email": "dean@c.edu", "streetName": "Columbia"}'
```

Which is double encoded, I need to get rid of the single quotes outside somehow, any ideas?

Comment: This single quotes shows you that this is a string.

Comment: Try `print(json.dumps(object, default=json_util.default)` and they magically disappear.

Comment: I suspect that your issue is that you are double-encoding your JSON (by using `jsonify` to send the data back (or else `json.dumps` again).

Comment: I thought so, but if I don't use it once, then it's TypeError: ObjectId('54522c44b8f9100002223fc0') is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 3):

Things are fine: the double quotes inside the string are as JSON expects.

The outer `'` quotes just indicate that this is a string within Python.

So you've got a regular string that happens to contain `"` inside it. For example: `'This is a string with " quotes'` is valid in Python and so is `"A string the other way around with ' quotes"`.

Comment: Agreed. json.dumps() returns a STRING (see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps). The strings inside this "output" string (enclosed in single quotes '') are enclosed in double quotes "", because that is a valid (and awesome) Python representation.

Comment: But when I do a simple curl such as : 
curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/api/Customers/54522c44b8f9100002223fc0

the returned value will be :

"{\"firstName\": \"Emre\", \"middleName\": \"n/a\", \"lastName\": \"S\", \"creation\": 1414671428727, \"streetNo\": \"116\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"54522c44b8f9100002223fc0\"}, \"email\": \"dean@c.edu\", \"streetName\": \"Columbia\"}"

which indicates double encoding no?

Comment: and if I return before json.dumps, I will get:

TypeError: ObjectId('54522c44b8f9100002223fc0') is not JSON serializable